# pro tools file structure

Tags: pro-tools, filing, osx

Hi guys,

We save our work onto a Raid drive and create the session on them too, although it seems that protools is also creating audio + fade file folders onto the main Hard Drive.

Any ideas on how we can stop this? had a look and can't find anything, it's almost creating a capture/scratch like FCP, it makes stuff confusing as sometimes files which are not in the session folder on the Raid appear on the HD drive.

This is on MAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why I use Nuendo :)

Comment: hey, i endorse nuendo, we use it at our studio, but sadly I work faster in ptools :) other than this silly hiccup! and real time exporting.. and :(

Comment: And... ;)
Yeah I guess it all comes down to training and habits I guess, what you're used to and such... I like the automation more in Pro Tools though but that's it I think

Answer (score 2):

Another way to prevent this is to set your system drive to "Transfer" status in the workspace browser - so it treats it like a CD/DVD drive and wont save anything onto it, ever.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem before.

Have you checked your disk allocation settings? Maybe you've different tracks assigned to different hard drives causing you probs

Answer (score 1):

I was always taught to check the disk allocations when opening a session because you never know what has changed since you last had the session up (could have moved the session around since then).  Even though my home sessions are allocated to the same place always, the habit is so ingrained in my muscle memory that I still do it by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I'm mistaken, but I've always understood that ProTools is not RAID-compatible (as far as running sessions).  Maybe it won't let you create files on that drive because of it?

Comment: yep. it definitely has issues with that. it can use a RAID as a transfer drive, but has potential problems otherwise.

Comment: Ah, okay cool.  I recall a buddy of mine had a problem with opening a session one time and discovered that for some reason SM was doing reference pulls instead of copying, so PT was trying to reference the source on the RAID and it spit out crazy errors.

Comment: Been using RAID drive with pro tools for a while now, no real major problems though.

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant, this was the problem looking at it. It seems importing session data from an older pro tools has mangled up defaults. (least what we think)

Thank you

Comment: No worries! Glad to help :) Sounds exactly like the prob I had previously. Was a major PITA until I figured out what was up!